# How to use RegEx for mod_security

Tags: apache-2.2, url, regex, mod-security, brute-force-attacks

I have a directory/site set-up like this on my Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) Server using mod_security + core ruleset/2.2.1

```
/website1/login.php
/website2/login.php
/website3/login.php
/websiteN/login.php
```

In my modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf I have

```
setvar:'tx.brute_force_protected_urls=login.php'
```

The problem is that it won't work unless I type in the full path for each of the login.php pages, like so:

```
setvar:'tx.brute_force_protected_urls=/website1/login.php /website2/login.php andSoOn'
```

I have tried other ways with RegEx to work around it (e.g. /(.*)/login.php) but I can't seem to get it.

So, question is basically; how do you enforce BFP on all pages called login.php on the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. In 'modsecurity_crs_11_brute_force.conf' I had to change line 39:

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "!@within %{tx.brute_force_protected_urls}"  ...
```

to

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "!@contains %{tx.brute_force_protected_urls}" ...
```

and in 'modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf', have:

```
setvar:'tx.brute_force_protected_urls=/login.php' ...
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setvar:'tx.brute_force_protected_urls=/login.php'
```

If it doesn't work, I suggest you enabling debug to see what the logs say.

Comment: I can't see anything of interest in the log, just says it's checking against the url (/login.php) and does not return with a valid hit. I was trying to use .htaccess to configure, which would make life easier, but it won't work with v2 for security reasons.

Comment: When `code` setvar:tx.brute_force_protected_urls=/login.php `code` the log states `code` Warning. Match of "within %{tx.brute_force_protected_urls}" against "REQUEST_FILENAME" required `code`